# discord.js - How to pick random mentioned users?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make system, that will dm mentioned users and author of the message with random message. But I'm stuck on getting all mentioned users from the message.

```
 const userName = message.author.username;
 const userName1 = message.mentions.users.get(1);
 const userName2 = message.mentions.users.get(2);
 const userName3 = message.mentions.users.get(3);

 const userId = message.author.id;

 message.channel.send(`Test ${userName}\nTest1 ${userName1}\nTest2 ${userName2}`)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the mentions collection by each user's username and assign it to a `usernames` array. Then use each element in that array.

```
const userName = message.author.username
const usernames = message.mentions.users.map(u => u.username)

const userId = message.author.id

message.channel.send(`Test ${userName}\nTest1 ${usernames[0]}\nTest2 ${usernames[1]}`)
```